# Is there a way to replace zero-length-string fields in all columns (at once) with NULL in a SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm hoping there's a better way other than handling it on individual columns:

```
SELECT
   IF(tbl.Field1 = '', NULL, tbl.Field1) AS 'Field 1',
   IF(tbl.Field2 = '', NULL, tbl.Field2) AS 'Field 2',
   ...
```

My concern is about the readability of the query and performance (although I haven't seen it slow down noticeably with the IF statements).

The reason for this action is to have normalised data ready for further processing, where it's clear that non-value is NULL and we don't have to be testing for both NULL and zero-length strings.

I have a read-only (SELECT) access to the database.

Comment: @Akina that is unfortunate, but `NULLIF()` is indeed much better as for the readability, thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you could just update the table to make all such values NULL

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [NULLIF](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/mysql-nullif-operator/) function:

```
SELECT
  NULLIF(field_1, '') AS field_1,
  NULLIF(field_2, '') AS field_2
  ....
```

Comment: `''` is the standard way to represent an empty string.  `""` is a MySQL extension.